# Neo4j Cypher: Friends*..3 Query Performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running a Cypher query that gets me all friends up to 3 hops away from a source:

```
MATCH (:Person {id:"768"})-[:KNOWS*1..3]-(friend:Person)
WITH DISTINCT friend
RETURN count(friend)
```

The query returns the right results but is taking longer that I would have expected since the graph has only 10k people in it. When I profile the query, I find that the `VarLengthExpand(All)` operator is returning a surprisingly large number of rows (~282k):

```
+-----------------------+----------------+--------+---------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows   | DB Hits |
+-----------------------+----------------+--------+---------+
| +ProduceResults       |              6 |      1 |       0 |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+
| +EagerAggregation     |              6 |      1 |       0 |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+
| +Distinct             |             35 |   9082 |       0 |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+
| +Filter               |             37 | 282635 |  282635 |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |             37 | 282635 |  290014 |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+
| +NodeIndexSeek        |              1 |      1 |       2 |
+-----------------------+----------------+--------+---------+
```

It appears that the `VarLengthExpand(All)` step is doing more work than is necessary. To check that, I looked at the number of nodes at each minimum distance away, and the number of incident `KNOWS` relationships to those nodes:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| min. dist. from src: | 0  | 1    | 2      | 3    |
|----------------------|----|------|--------|------|
| nodes                | 1  | 12   | 2815   | 6270 |
| incident knows rels  | 12 | 3697 | 164828 |      |
----------------------------------------------------
```

So we see that node 768 has 12 direct friends, 2,815 friends-of-friends, and 6,270 friends-of-friends-of-friends. The friends-of-friends group has 164,828 incident `KNOWS` relationships, and of all the nodes touched by those relationships, 6,270 are nodes that have a minimum distance of 3 to the source node.

So, if a traversal were to proceed in a breadth-first-search fashion from the source... in theory it would only need to do ~ 12 + 3,697 + 164,828 = 168,537 reads, which is a lot less than 282k.

Does anybody know what's going on here, and whether or not there is a better way to formulate this query?

Comment: Please show the query you used to produce your minimum distance results.

Comment: @ellitron You have not tried to use directional relationships in a query?